# GraphRequest throwing NullPointerException when trying to get the ID of a user onCompleted?

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, nullpointerexception

Almost 95% of my users pass the login process without an issue, but there are times when I get this exception when I try: editor.putString("fbId", id). Why? If onSuccess gets called I assume the object would have been populated, then why the error or possible null respone??

Please help me out, I am getting crazy on this!

Thanks!

exception:

> Android Version: android version: 4.3
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.cerculdivelor.SplashActivity$2$1.onCompleted(SplashActivity.java:90)
>   at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:304) at
>   com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1379) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Method:

```
private void onFblogin() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                                // Application code
                                try {

               /*** line 90 -->***/ String id = object.getString("id");
                                    String name = object.getString("name");
                                    String email = object.getString("email");
                                    //String birthday = object.getString("birthday"); <-- error if people don't have this completed

                                    Log.i("TAG", email + " " + id + " " + " " + name);

                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                    editor.putString("fbId", id);
                                    editor.putString("name", name);
                                    editor.putString("email", email);
                                    editor.commit();

                                    HttpConActivity http = new HttpConActivity(getApplication());
                                    http.saveToServer(id, name, email);

                                    finish();

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i("TAG", "Canceled!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Error!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: What getting in `Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());` line?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK hmmm, I have forgot to include that Log into the try block, and unfortunately I can't recreate the error. I will include it inside the try block and wait for the result. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check for Errors in the `GraphJSONObjectCallback - GraphResponse`.
The Documentation says, that `JSONObject object` can be null, so you should not assume that is not null.

Keep in mind that you communicate with a server.
You should always expect errors and handle them.

So something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
    if (error != null) {
        // handle your error
        return;
    }

    try {
        String id = object.getString("id");
        ...
```

Comment: good point, thanks. But if onError(FacebookException e) happens why does it execute onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) too?? Can these two be called in the same time?? This does not make sense.

Comment: No you are executing `GraphRequest` in `onSuccess`. I mean even if the login was successful, the graph `GraphRequest`  fail. For example with a poor internet connection with a Timeout or whatever.

Comment: by the way, the FB Doc mention "public int getErrorCode();" for returning any error, you may correct it. Thanks.

Comment: @EdmondTamas so you called getErrorCode() on which object?